# Any work around starting UI from OSX daemon

Tags: macos, daemon, agent

I have a running daemon which downloads installers (pkg) and installs it using install command. Installer copies UI plist file into the /Library/LaunchAgent therefore UI can be started after user logged-in. 
But end of installation, install should start UI. I understand UI can not be started from daemon due to osx window server architecture where daemon could not directly start any UI process.

Could you please suggest any work around therefore UI can be started without asking reboot or logged-out/in?

Regards,
Anand Choubey

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `launchctl bsexec`, see `man launchctl` and OS X Technical Notes on bootstrap namespaces for additional information.

1. Pick a logged in user for which you'd like to do it; note that there may be several or none. Current console user is the one that owns `/dev/console`; if the owner UID is 0 (root), then no one is logged in.
2. Find `loginwindow` process belonging to that user UID.
3. Exec `/bin/launchctl bsexec PID_OF_THAT_LOGINWINDOW_PROCESS command args ...` to perform command just as if it had been run by the users themselves. This allows to start GUI processes, perform `launchctl setenv/start/load` etc. Don't forget to `sudo`/`setuid` to the target user UID.

If you need to start a LaunchAgent, you should do that with `launchctl load` rather than by running the agent directly, otherwise it will not be present in `launchd` like it should.

Comment: So, there was enough time for alternative answers but it was already hard to beat your excellent answer. +100, thanks for the info!